# Show that this sequence obeys the WLLN

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_n)$ be an indepdendent sequence of real random variables distributed thus:

$$P(X_n=n)=P(X_n=-n)=\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{n \ln(n+1)},$$

$$P(X_n=0)=1- \frac{1}{n \ln(n+1)} \hspace{1cm} n\in\mathbb{N}$$

With the aid of [Theorem 10.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RBzv.png) show that this sequence obeys the weak law of large numbers. *Hint*: The function $x\mapsto \frac{x}{\ln(x+1)}$ is strictly increasing on the interval $[1,\infty)$.

First I notice that $P(X_1=0)<0$ so I suppose we mean $n\geq 2$. Second we see that $E(X_n)=0$ and that $E(X^2_n)=\frac{n}{\ln(n+1)}$ for all $n$. Hence the condition

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} V(X_i) =0$$

of [Theorem 10.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RBzv.png) is statisfied and the WLLN holds. But why do we need the hint for?

Comment: How do you show that $\frac 1 {n^{2}} \sum V(X_i) \to 0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh right I realize this is not immediate. How can you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $\frac n {\ln (n+1)}$ is increasing shows that $\frac 1 {n^{2}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac k {\ln (k+1)} \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}} n\frac n {\ln (n+1)} =\frac 1 {ln (n+1)} \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still we should start the sequence at $n=2$ right?

Comment: @Alphie Yes, that is a  good observation.